# How to run android as peripheral to receive data from central programmatically

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing android BLE service to control Keypad BLE central. In this option, Keypad runs as Central and Android app will run as peripheral, and app advertises to keypad central.

How I can handle android as peripheral? I am newbie in this field.
Example code is very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

At first make sure that Keypad BLE support [Gatt](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html) protocol.
In this case you can implement Gatt protocol on your device. Please check Keypad BLE documentation. You should implement Service and Characteristic r/w in your app.